# TeamCity running bat file sucessfully but did not run the selenium tests

Tags: .net, batch-file, selenium, teamcity, specflow

I'm having a problem with *TeamCity* that runs a batch file I've created to run my *SpecFlow* tests.

The batch file runs `SpecRun.exe` and what I should see is that *Chrome* pops up and the tests begin to run. (This is not a local application, so no need to get IIS running, etc.) The tests are selenium tests that run against a site. All works as expected when running the batch file from the command line.

I have a build step in *TeamCity* that runs the batch file through a command line build step. But when I run the build step, I get `Success` in the log which tells me that the batch file has ran, but no *Chrome* window popped up nor have the tests actually be run.

My batch file contents are:

```
cd C:\Users\carlb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SITS_Automation\packages\SpecRun.Runner.1.2.0\tools
start SpecRun.exe run ../../SITS_Automation/default.srprofile /report:../../SITS_Automation/TestResults/SITS_Report.html
```

What could be the mistake in my batch code resulting in selenium tests not being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start command starts SpecRun and any other program in another process and so does not wait for it completition.
Remove the start or add the /WAIT parameter to it.

Answer (score 0):

Path to set current directory contains a space.

You need therefore

```
cd "C:\Users\carlb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SITS_Automation\packages\SpecRun.Runner.1.2.0\tools"
```

or even better

```
cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SITS_Automation\packages\SpecRun.Runner.1.2.0\tools"
```

It can be read on last page output by running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window that strings with a **space** or one of the following characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` must be enclosed in double quotes.

With option `/D` command **CD** processes also a switch to a directory on a different drive than the current drive. And predefined environment variable `USERPROFILE` contains path to profile directory of the current user.

And remove command `start` if `SpecRun` is a console application to run this application from within same command process with halting execution of batch file until this console application terminated itself.

But if `SpecRun` is a GUI application use

```
start "SpecRun" /wait SpecRun.exe run ..\..\SITS_Automation\default.srprofile /report:..\..\SITS_Automation\TestResults\SITS_Report.html
```

`"SpecRun"` in double quotes is just a window **title** string which can be also just `""` for an empty string or completely left out on this command line because no other parameter is enclosed in double quotes. Optional **title** is often a required parameter if any string on **start** line is enclosed in double quotes because command **start** interprets the first double quoted string often as title string. Therefore it is simply more safe to specify on usage of **start** always a title string if this is just an empty string to avoid an unexpected behavior.

You should also use `\` instead of `/` in paths to a directory or file as the backslash is the directory separator on Windows and not the forward slash as on Unix/Linux/Mac. Command processor `cmd.exe` replaces the forward slashes by backslashes in file and directory paths on execution of the batch file. But it would be nevertheless better to specify file and folder paths with correct directory separator for Windows, except the started application requires forward slashes because being (badly) ported from *nix to Windows.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `start /?`